# Find missing records in ONE-TO-MANY relationship query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables:

Class

| Id | ClassName |
| --- | --- |
| *guid* | 1A |
| *guid* | 2A |

Subject

| Id | SubjectName |
| --- | --- |
| *guid* | Math |
| *guid* | Biography |

SubjectOfEachClass

| Id | ClassId | SubjectId | TeacherName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *guid* | *guid* | *guid* | James Bond |

The way I wanted these tables to work is:

- There will be 10 classes in table Class.
- There will be 10 subjects in table Subject.
- Each class will has 10 subjects and for 10 classes there will be 100 records.

I ran into some problems, I queried the SubjectOfEachClass table and there are only 95 records.
The query command I use to find the missing subjects is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Subject s
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM SubjectOfEachClass
    WHERE ClassId = 'guid'
) AS sc ON s.Id = sc.SubjectId
```

I replaced the ClassId several times until I found the class that misses some of the subjects.

I reckon this way of querying is not efficient at all. If I have 100 subjects and 100 classes, there will no chance that I will find the missing subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to find every missing subject in all classes:

```
select c.id, c.classname , s.id , s.SubjectName
from class c
cross apply Subject s
where not exists (
   select 1 from SubjectOfEachClass sc 
   where sc.classid = c.id and sc.subjectid = s.id
)
```

Comment: Thanks alot sir, it works perfectly, I seems like I have a lot more to learn about SQL

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.id AS classId,
       count(sc.id) AS countOfSubjects
FROM SubjectOfEachClass AS sc
INNER JOIN Classes AS c ON c.id = sc.classId
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY countOfSubjects
```

The abnormal values will be floated.

Comment: Not the soluton I wanted but a great way to see all of the records. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 1):

Your primary table should be `SubjectOfEachClass`, then those foreign tables `Subject` and `Class` will `join` your primary table.

```
select *
from SubjectOfEachClass sc
inner join Subject s on s.guid=sc.guid
inner join Class c on c.guid=sc.guid
where sc.ClassId = 'guid'
```

Comment: Thanks sir, I will put more thought into making table relationship before creating them next time.